# Get all commits in merge commit

Tags: git

I have 2 branches: `master` and `feature`. I am on my branch `feature`. I create 2 commits:

```
user:~/tmp$ git status
On branch feature

user:~/tmp$ echo foo >foo
user:~/tmp$ git add foo
user:~/tmp$ git commit -m "foo"

user:~/tmp$ echo bar >foo
user:~/tmp$ git commit -am "bar"
```

Then I checkout `master` branch and merge branch `feature` without fast-forwarding:

```
user:~/tmp$ git checkout master
user:~/tmp$ git merge feature --no-ff
```

This creates merge commit:

```
user:~/tmp$ git log
commit 6077908acc97810b27f2ac53cdeed4df1c5dd6cf (HEAD -> master)
Merge: 5a22c43 63ef35e

    Merge branch 'feature1' into feature

    * feature:
      bar
      foo
```

Is it possible to know which commits were present in the merge commit, other than by merge commit message (which could be  modified)?

Comment: `Merge: 5a22c43 63ef35e` is this not what you want?

Comment: @NghiaBui those are are hashes of merge commit; the first one is the previous HEAD of `master` branch, the second one is HEAD of `feature` branch. The second hash is the one I want, but it is just one; if there were more commits (or less) in the branch, I would still have only 2 hashes, whereas I want to know hashes of all commits that were in the merge commit.

Comment: try a more informative `git log` like: `git log --pretty=oneline --graph` is this what you want?

Comment: @NghiaBui This looks very close to what I want, thank you! Is it possible to get this information somehow text-only?

Comment: The command actually produces text in your console, no GUI involved here.

Comment: @NghiaBui It also has some ascii-graphics, which I would need to get rid of, hence the question.

Comment: Without such an intuitive graphics, I think you have to manually and repeatedly type `git cat-file -p <commit hash>` to see the parent commit of the concerned commit.

Answer (score 2):

You can log the commits of the merged branch with the following:

```
git log 6077908^..6077908^2
```

To be read as "log all the commits which are not in the first parent of the merge commit (`6077908^`, which is the last commit of master before the merge) but which are in the second parent of the merge commit (`6077908^2`, which is the branch you merged).